# Cut command stored in variable will not work

Tags: bash, shell-script, cut

Can someone explain why I cannot store the cut command in a variable??

```
user:~$ echo "foo bii doo" | cut -d ' ' -f 2
bii # as expected
# now put cut command into a variable:
user:~$ c="cut -d ' ' -f 2"
user:~$ echo "foo bii doo" | $c
cut: "'": No such file or directory
user:~$ c="cut -d \  -f 2"
user:~$ echo "foo bii doo" | $c
foo bii doo
```

It is not a general quoting problem because tr works:

```
user:~$ t="tr -d 'oo'"
user:~$ echo "foo bii doo" | $t
f bii d
```

(I am on Debian 12 using bash)
Solved the problem in other ways already. I ask just to know why I wasted 3 hours debugging :)

Comment: Put simply, variables are for data, functions are for commands. Don't try to put a command in a simple scalar (string) variable - as you've discovered it is highly unlikely to work the way you expect

Comment: Oh, and it is a quoting problem. Try `echo "don't forget" | $t`

Comment: The unquoted `$c` will be subject to *word splitting* (and globbing) - so `' '` becomes two separate tokens `'` and `'`. See also [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Ah thank you guys, you guessed it I am not a scripting Pro.
But then for this specific code examples: why is the 'tr' working?

Comment: It isn't. See my example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a way, it's not a quoting problem, it's an expansion problem. Variable expansion is not text replacement, and the data you get from the variable is *not* parsed as code, meaning neither quotes nor backslash escapes or any other shell syntax is processed. Instead, the expanded value is word-split on whitespace, any whitespace. This means you can't use word splitting to store multiple arbitrary strings in one string.

The `tr` command you used *seems* to work, because adding single quotes to its argument doesn't change what it does with the `o`s. As Chris Davies mentioned in a comment, if you do this:

```
$ t="tr -d 'oo'"
$ echo "don't forget" | $t
dnt frget
```

you'll see the quotes got included in the list of characters for `tr` to remove. `tr` got the argument `'oo'`, not the argument `oo`.
If you wanted to have `tr` remove spaces, you'd run into issues, same as with `cut`:

```
$ t="tr -d ' '"
$ echo "don't forget" | $t
usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2
       tr [-Ccu] -d string1
       tr [-Ccu] -s string1
       tr [-Ccu] -ds string1 string2
```

That tries to run `tr` with the three arguments `-d`, `'` and `'`, which doesn't match how it's supposed to be used, so it prints the usage help.

The way to do it is to create a function instead, e.g.:

```
c() {
    cut -d \  -f 2
}
echo "foo bii doo" | c
```

giving `bii`.

See:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. Lesson learned, as @chris-davies also commented: Don't try to put a command in a simple scalar (string) variable